# Copying sample of file from hdfs to local fs?

Tags: hadoop

Ok,

A very stupid question...

I have a large file in hdfs

```
/user/input/foo.txt
```

I want to copy first 100 lines from this location to local filesystem...

And the data is very sensitive so i am bit hesistant to experiment.

What is the right way to copy sample data from hdfs to local fs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is not compressed:

```
bin/hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file |head -100 > /path/to/local/file
```

If the file is compressed:

```
bin/hadoop fs -text /path/to/file |head -100 > /path/to/local/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way that ensures victory:

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /user/input/foo.txt /path/to/local/file | head -100
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `head` program to extract the few lines from the beginning of a file, eg:

```
$ head /user/input/foo.txt -n100
```

(where `n` determines the number of lines to extract), and redirect output to the file of your choice:

```
$ head /user/input/foo.txt -n100 > /path/to/you/output/file
```

Comment: Apologies Fraz, I misread the question and associated tagging. In all honesty I'm not a Hadoop pro, but this may work for you:

$ hadoop fs -cat hdfs://node/user/input/foo.txt | head -n100 > /path/to/local